# Jquery HTML or AFTER or APPEND with HTML table tag

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_after2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function afterText() {
  $("#tblGrid").html("<td>NameName2</td><td>Budget Value 2</td></tr><tr><td>NameName3</td><td>Budget Value 3</td>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tbody>
 <th><h4>Name Heading</h4></th>
 <th>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Budget Heading</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
   </table>
  </th>
     
 <tr id="tblGrid"></tr>
 <tr><td>NameName1</td><td>Budget Value 1</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="afterText()">Button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT is something like this after clicking button:

Name Heading Budget Heading

NameName3    Budget Value 3

NameName1    Budget Value 1

**Button**

Could you help in understanding where is value with number "2" is going?

Output expected:

Name Heading Budget Heading

NameName2    Budget Value 2

NameName3    Budget Value 3

NameName1    Budget Value 1

**Button**

Also every time we click button, it should not append 2 and 3, but clear old iteration values. Suggestions please!

Comment: You are trying to add a `</tr>` inside an existing tr element... Which is invalid HTML... Maybe the browser is discarding everything before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html table structure is slightly incorrect. I have changed the structure of the `thead` tag. And you don't need to use the `h4` tag for this.

I defined your `tr` tag with **id=tblGrid** as `tbody` tag.

Also, you are using the `html()` method. But this method **overwrites** the content. Better use the `append()` method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function afterText() {
                $("#tblGrid").append("<tr><td>NameName2</td><td>Budget Value 2</td></tr><tr><td>NameName3</td><td>Budget Value 3</td></tr>");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name Heading</th>
                    <th>Budget Heading</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tblGrid">
                <tr>
                    <td>NameName1</td>
                    <td>Budget Value 1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onclick="afterText()">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi s.kuznetsov, Thank you for your help. I am able to use this method and do my stuff now. Only thing I added was using empty before append (...empty().append...) because on multiple clicks of button, it retains old value and I don't want that so had to make some adjustments for NameName1 and Budget Value 1, but this works for me.

Comment: @HardikNuwal, Hello. Yes, method append() dynamically adds the same values. So empty() makes sense. Happy to help.